# Python script no longer running as cron job

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a water pump setup for my greenhouse and I use a raspberry pi as a pump timer. It's been working for weeks and then I ran the script that actually activates the pump and it wouldn't shut off. Now the cronjob I'd setup to run the script is also not working.

So basically, I had a script to run the water pump

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import datetime

channel = 21

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(channel, gpio.OUT)


def pump_on(pin):
    gpio.output(pin, gpio.HIGH)

def pump_off(pin):
    gpio.output(pin, gpio.LOW)


#setting up cronjob to start at startup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        pump_on(channel)
        datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("...Activating Sprinkler...: ", str(datetime))
        time.sleep(75)
        print("...Deactivating Sprinkler...")
        pump_off(channel)
        gpio.cleanup()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        gpio.cleanup()
        print("Interrupted!")
        pass
```

It's run through this cronjob using crontab -e

```
30 15 * * * /home/pi/Documents/water_pump.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

I have another script that checks if the pi is turned on every hour (it's solar powered so I wanna see if there are off times with the battery)

```
0 * * * * /home/pi/Documents/time_log.py >> ~/time.log 2>&1
```

This one still works fine.

But a few days ago I ran
./water_pump.py

And it didn't shut off after 75 seconds and I needed to manually shut down the system, and now the cronjob just for that no longer works.

Any advice would be extremely appreciated.

Edit: 
grep CRON /var/log/syslog output here: https://imgur.com/a/jfC9eRw

It's long and I can't embed images

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the line from the cron job and then pasted it onto the end and it worked so, guess that's how to fix it.